# Google Play Store: How to "lock-up" an app name

Tags: google-play

**Scenario**

I have an app that I've been working on for 6 months. I have already made the app for native iOS and about to put it on the Apple App Store. I know that I will want to work on the Android version of the app starting soon, but I would like to "lock-up" the name of the app on the Google Play Store before I begin working on it. I would hate to work another 6 months working just to get to the end and find that someone else took that name.

**Question**

How do I save an app name on the Google Play Store for future distribution?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reservation of app names in Google store and not programming related.

Comment: My question did not **require** code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to, Duplicates of names are allowed in Google Play. :)